# Bought a book that is in the public domain ... but the T&A of company says I can't redistribute it

Tags: copyright

I purchased an ebook that I'm 100% sure is in the public domain (published in 70's, no copyright notice or copyright reg with us office).

However, the company I bought the ebook from has this in their terms and agreements that I had to agree to before checking out:

"all content included on this site, such as ... digital downloads ... is the property of [company]".

To clarify the website that I purchased the book from is the same company that originally published/ wrote the book.

So, my question: While this document is in the public domain, can I legally redistribute it, or due to the terms and agreements can I not?

Comment: What year was it published? That may matter because, as mentioned below, US copyright law was changed in 1978. Also, the author automatically gets copyright whether or not she registers the book or uses a copyright mark. Registration just gets the copyright holder some extra legal rights.

Comment: What *exactly* was stated in the T&A? This is important in that there is quite a difference between asserting copyright rights vs. asserting ownership rights. From the abbreviated wording you have included, it sounds like the company is asserting that they have *ownership* rights to every digital download. That's significantly different, and has different answers, than that the company is asserting that they hold the copyright to the content which is being downloaded.

Comment: @Makyen What does it mean to "own" intellectual property other than being able to assert copyright?

Comment: @Barmar It's not about the intellectual property; it's about the actual copy. The "owner" is saying they retain ownership of the copy you download. In other words, you are renting, not buying.

Comment: @Justaguy OK -- I think the usual term is "licensing". But I think you have to own the copyright for that to be possible.

Comment: @Barmar There's a difference between the company asserting they own the copyright and asserting that they actually *own every copy* of the work. If they own the copyright, then they can prevent copying or distributing copies of the work, but they can't prevent someone transferring *ownership* of the copy the person purchased, and the owner doing that in any manner they choose. If the company is asserting *ownership*, then they are claiming the right to restrict can be done with a copy by the person who possesses that copy (e.g. that they can't sell/give/transfer that copy to someone else).

Comment: For example, asserting ownership rights is done in the computer software industry where some/many companies claim to only be selling a *license to use*, not actual ownership of a copy of the program. In such cases, the companies claim that the possession of a copy of the program is only to facilitate the exercise of the license to use the software and that the possession does not constitute actual ownership of that copy. An example of a company that does this is Microsoft, at least the last time I fully read their license agreements.

Comment: @Barmar You are right: "Licensing," is clearly what I was talking about. Thanks.

Comment: If the book was written in 1978 or 1979, then it is almost certainly _not_ in the public domain unless the author has specifically released it as such.

Comment: What does "T&A" stand for here? I've heard of "T&C" for "terms and conditions", but the only context I've heard "T&A" in is in reference to female sexual characteristics.

Comment: Copyright usually ends 70 years after the death of the author. If the book was not published posthumously by at least 30 years then the book **is surely NOT in the public domain**. You seem to have gotten all of it wrong. If an author wants to make their work in the public domain before 70 years from their death they must *add* an explicit note about that. No note = copyrighted.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and add an explanation of why you think that a book written in the 1970's would no longer be copyrighted. Perhaps then we can understand your logic. It would also help if you'd tell us what book it is that you're talking about, and who the ebook publisher is. Thanks.

Comment: If you’re 100% sure that it’s in the public domain, then there should be myriads of other sources where you can get the content and repurpose it into a package which you 100% know you can redistribute. Don’t try to redistribute this particular publisher’s ebook.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Actually, in the UK copyright is an inalienable right. The author can choose not to enforce any rights he may have, but a work cannot simply be passed into the public domain.

Answer (score 44):

### The text *may* be public domain in the [United States](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap3.html)

It depends on [when](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_States#Duration_of_copyright) it was created/published.

### The eBook is subject to its own copyright

The eBook itself is a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) and subject to its own copyright protection. The translation of an ink and paper book into an eBook contains enough artistic choice to trigger copyright protection.

If the original is really public domain, you can copy the text but not the eBook.

Comment: This reminds me of the case of digitized videos of vintage newsreels someone asked about a year or two ago; just because the underlying material is public domain doesn't mean that the company holding the digital version is obligated to provide you with a free copy in the redistributable format of your choice.

Comment: If the translation to eBook format is entirely automated, would that still allow it to have its own copyright protection? There's no "artistic choice" in a mechanical transformation.

Comment: There is; someone programmed a computer to perform that transformation in that manner.

Comment: Apparently the question of whether copyright of software extends to that software's output is blurry and fairly unresolved, see [Design Data Corp. v. Unigate Enterprise, Inc.](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infco20170209141) for an example of it not being the case.

Comment: I think the statement that compiling the eBook is "enough artistic choice" requires a reference.

Comment: @jeffronicus: Copyright law urgently needs some tweaking on such issues.  Someone who owns every copy of a work that is entering the public domain should be able to profit from efforts to make the work available to the public, but should not be entitled to profit by burying the only copies of the original public domain work.  What I'd like to see would be a means of acquiring a short term "restoration copyright" on condition that one ensure that the original work be escrowed for release after 10 years or so.

Comment: @DPenner1: While the copyright notice requirement caused some problems, bigger problems can arise from ambiguity over the parts of a work for which copyright is claimed.  Many applications can convert documents into executable programs for the purpose of allowing people without the main application to use those documents in limited ways.  A purchaser such the application would be entitled to distribute executables produced thereby (that would be the purpose of the feature) but would not be entitled to authorize recipients thereof to reverse-engineer the code therein.

Answer (score 11):

Part of something being in the Public Domain is that anyone can take that work, make a minor change, and copyright the result for themselves. Not the original of course, but their custom version. Public Domain status isn't "infectious" to derived works like the GPL (copyleft) is. This is how the [mashup genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_novels#Copyright_issues) of fiction regularly operates.

In this case, most likely the publisher is asserting copyright to their digital conversion of the PD source material. I have also heard of tweaks being something as simple as adding pictures to the text.

Legally you can probably get around the issue by copying only the unmodified portions of the text, but its possible they stuck some land-mines in there (eg: modernized spellings here or there), specifically to catch people doing that. Safer just to find yourself a true PD copy (like on Project Gutenberg) and work from that.

Answer (score 10):

I do not think you should be 100% sure it is in the public domain. As of sometime in 1978 copyrightable material is automaticity copyright as of is original fixation - no copyright notice required.

Comment: January 1, 1978. If the work was created after that date, it has an automatic copyright term of the lifetime of the author + 70 years.

Comment: Is there any requirement that a work which is primarily based on public-domain identify any portions or aspects upon which copyright is claimed?  If I buy a book of Shakespeare sonnets, but the publisher has replaced #57 with some original text of his own creation (without indicating that it wasn't written by Shakespeare), would the publisher be entitled to sue for copyright infringement anyone who reproduces "Sonnet #57" from that book?  If so, that would seem a major defect in the notice requirement.

Comment: What notice requirement?

Comment: I guess you're asking about the likelihood of *winning* such a lawsuit and being awarded damages, @supercat.  The details matter, but generally speaking, although the chance of the publisher winning the suit is reasonably good, the chance of them being awarded damages is small.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: Sorry--I meant the a defect in the rule *eliminating* the notice requirement.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The issue wouldn't merely be monetary damages, but also with things like injunctive relief.  If a company were to incorporate part of the "Shakespearean" into its logo, having to redo all artwork containing that logo could be very expensive whether or not the company was required to pay the author any monetary damages for infringements that occurred prior to a cease-and-desist notice.

Comment: @supercat, the scenario you describe is possible, but I think also unlikely.  Always the details matter, but if Big Publisher misrepresents the contents of their book as you describe, then when they sue Another Company for copyright violation, AC is likely to argue, very reasonably, that BP is estopped from enforcing their rights with respect to the substitute sonnet because of their misrepresentation.

Answer (score 1):

The work is not protected by copyright, however, you agreed not to copy or distribute the copy you obtained from this service. That is enforceable, see ProcCD v. Zeidenberg.

Note that only you are bound by the terms because only you agreed to them. Were someone who hadn't agreed to the terms somehow get access to your copy and make and distributed copies of it, they would not be violating any law or agreement (at least, not that I can think of).

Comment: *ProcCD* does not apply to this situation. *ProcCD*, followed another phone book case, *Feist*. In *Feist*, the SCt rejected the "sweat of the brow" standard for copyright for the "minimum of originality" standard. This standard is based on the constitutional justification for copyright: "to promote the progress of science and useful arts..." Turning a text into an ebook has been held to be original enough to warrant copyright; compiling lists of phone numbers has not.

Comment: @Justaguy That part of the holding doesn't apply. But the rest of it does -- that even though there's no copyright protection available, the agreement not to distribute the work is enforceable on someone who agreed to it.

Comment: Ooops! I should have said the "no copyright" part of *ProcCD* does not apply, but the part about agreeing not to distribute does. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: I think my first paragraph is very clear -- you have a work that is not protected by copyright, however you have agreed not to copy or distribute the copy you obtained, and that's enforceable. This is precisely what was held in ProCD v. Zeidenberg, a case also dealing with a work not protected by copyright.

Comment: Don't forget the possibility of a common design.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How do you know it is not protected by copyright? The OP is confused about the basics of copyright law, so his claim is worthless. Under US copyright law, whether the book is in the public domain depends on facts such as who wrote it and when.

Comment: @Justaguy I can only go by what the OP says, and he says he's 100% sure it's in the public domain. If the OP is wrong, then the answer is still correct for any case where the content is in fact in the public domain.